# Count the number of 0 and 1 in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file (see below), and I would like to count the number of 1's and of 0's:

```
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
...
```

I tried  to use awk but it doesn't work, for example, to count the number of 1's:

```
awk -F "1\n" '{print NF-1}'
```

How shall I do it?

I assume the file only contains 1's and 0's, and each line is just a single number. But I more like to know how to generalize to the case for counting the occurrences of a specific line in a file.

Answer (score 6):

This counts the number of ones and zeros in `filename`:

```
$ sort <filename | uniq -c
      5 0
      5 1
```

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/0/{zero++} /1/{one++} END{printf "0: %d\n1: %d\n", zero, one}' filename
```

With `grep`, needing two commands:

```
grep -c 1 filename
grep -c 0 filename
```

---

For a string that covers the entire line:

```
grep -cFx 'target string' filename
```

Presumably your string might contain characters that have special meaning in regex, so we need to use `-F`. `-x` specifies that the whole line must match.

With awk:

```
awk '$0 == "target string" {count++} END {print count}'
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you generalize to the case for counting the occurrences of a specific line (not part of a line) in a file?

Comment: @Tim the target string should cover the entire line?

Comment: @Tim see updates.

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything but 0 and print the character counts:

```
tr -cd 0 < file | wc -m
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to grep for lines matching exact "0" (or "1") and count the resulting lines:

```
grep "^0$" filename | wc -l
```

=> 5

```
grep "^1$" filename | wc -l
```

=> 5

Or count both alternatives in a single grep:

```
grep "^[01]$" filename | wc -l
```

=> 10

Answer (score 1):

Ed, man! !man ed:

```
$ ed -s file <<EOT
g/0/d
n
u
g/1/d
n
EOT

13  1
17  0
```

Comment: This won't work OK if  lines not matching 0 or 1 are present in the file. If you want to avoid that and still emulate the `sort | uniq -c` behavior you'll have to use `v` instead of `g` e.g. `v/^0$/d` ....

Comment: @don_crissti that's correct. This obviously also have problems when the file is empty or doesn't contain any `0` or `1`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -n0E 'say tr/0//, "+",tr/1//'
```

or following OP tentative:

```
awk -v RS=1 'END{print NR-1}'
```